# compare 2 object arrays and return the elements in first array as true if it exists in second array, or as false if it does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 object arrays

```
const options = [
  { value: 'opt1', label: 'opt1' },
  { value: 'opt2', label: 'opt2' },
  { value: 'opt3', label: 'opt3' },
  { value: 'opt4', label: 'opt4' }
]

const selected = [
  { value: 'opt1', key: '1' },
  { value: 'opt2', key: '2' }
]
```

I need to compare these two arrays and get result as

```
result =
  { 'opt1', true },
  { 'opt2', true },
  { 'opt3', false },
  { 'opt4', false }
]
```

since opt1 and opt2 exists in second array. I know there are lots of methods, but what would be the shortest method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest one that I personally could imagine.

```
const result = options.map(o => ({ [o.value]: !!selected.find(s => s.value === o.value) }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `map` to get the mapped values first of the selected and then a map the array `options` using a logic to ask for the existence of a value within the `selected` array.  Finally, use [`computed-property-names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to build the desired output.

```js
const options = [  { value: 'opt1', label: 'opt1' },  { value: 'opt2', label: 'opt2' },  { value: 'opt3', label: 'opt3' },  { value: 'opt4', label: 'opt4' }],
      selected = [  { value: 'opt1', key: '1' },  { value: 'opt2',key: '2' }],
      mapped = selected.map(({value}) => value),
      result = options.map(({value}) => ({[value]: mapped.includes(value)}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return options.map(v => {
  let newObj = {};
  newObj[v.value] = selected.find(option => { return 
  option.value == v.value }) !== undefined;
  return newObj;
})
```